# Azure blob Storage: Synchronous copy of block blobs across containers within the same Azure storage account is not working

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the [startCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.startcopy?view=azure-java-legacy#com_microsoft_azure_storage_blob_CloudBlockBlob_startCopy_final_CloudBlockBlob_String_boolean_final_AccessCondition_final_AccessCondition_BlobRequestOptions_OperationContext_) API from  azure-storage java sdk version 8.6.5 to copy blobs between containers within the same storage account.

```
String copyJobId = cloudBlockBlob.startCopy(srcBlob, srcBlob.getProperties().getContentMD5(), true,
                                            null, null, null, null)
```

And I am getting the following exception -

```
[17:25:42.976] - [STDERR] com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The specified resource does not exist.
[17:25:42.977] - [STDERR]   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:87)
[17:25:42.977] - [STDERR]   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305)
[17:25:42.977] - [STDERR]   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:196)
[17:25:42.978] - [STDERR]   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopy(CloudBlob.java:791)
[17:25:42.978] - [STDERR]   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob.startCopy(CloudBlockBlob.java:302)
[17:25:42.978] - [STDERR]   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob.startCopy(CloudBlockBlob.java:252)
```

If I use the other [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.startcopy?view=azure-java-legacy#com_microsoft_azure_storage_blob_CloudBlockBlob_startCopy_final_CloudBlockBlob_) without sync, copy works fine -

```
String copyJobId = cloudBlockBlob.startCopy(srcBlob); //This works
```

Any idea if I am missing anything here?

Thanks in advance!!!

EDITS - Adding the screenshot of exception using the test sample code by @Bowman.
[image]

Comment: I have post the code, it seems copy with sync is no problem on my side. You can check what is the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Below code works fine on my side:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob;


public class testbowman {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String accountname = "0730bowmanwindow";
        String accountkey = "xxxxxx";
        String containername = "test";
        String source_blobname = "test1.txt";
        String sink_blobname = "test2.txt";
        StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(accountname,accountkey);
        CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials);
        CloudBlobClient client = account.createCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = client.getContainerReference(containername);;
        CloudBlockBlob source_cbb = container.getBlockBlobReference(source_blobname);
        CloudBlockBlob sink_cbb = container.getBlockBlobReference(sink_blobname);
        sink_cbb.startCopy(source_cbb,source_cbb.getProperties().getContentMD5(),true,null,null,null,null);
        System.out.println("This is a test.");
    }
}
```

And this is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testbowman</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
            <version>8.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And this is my storage configuration:

[image]

Success copy with sync:

[image]

You can check what is the different between you can me.(By the way, `startCopy(CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob)` also works on my side.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bowman for code sample. This API with `syncCopy=true` does not work for me with the same test code as yours and same storage config. I am getting the same old exception `com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The specified resource does not exist.`

Comment: @Arti Have you already prepared the source file? The code really works for me, maybe you can report this bug to the MS, such as post this issue on the Github.

Comment: I used the same code as yours which I added as screenshot above. And I also changed the storage account config to match what you have. I will post this issue on Github as well.

Comment: @Arti Great! Any update please let me know.:)